# How to echo an value from mysql by equating variable to row table

Tags: mysql

My table name is 'new' and it has 3 rows, id name and title, and i also have a variable 'hi'. What is the mysql query for, if variable $hi(introduce) == value(introduce) in the 'title' row from 'new' table. then echo introduce.

```
$hi ="introduce";

--------------------- 
id | name | title |
---------------------
 1 | hi   | introduce
 2 | hello| tell me
```

Comment: my query displays all records from the table,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "select * from `new` where `title` = '$hi'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about echo but you can select all rows where title=introduce like this:

```
SELECT * FROM new WHERE title = 'introduce';
```